# Any reason for database to detach by it self after attach in sqlite3?

Tags: database, go, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 driver for go - http://mattn.github.io/go-sqlite3.

After attaching 3 databases to my original db and making sure i never close one of them,
I loss the connection for the attached databases in the middle of my go program.
is there any special reason that can cause that?
would appreciate some help.

Comment: Are you *really* sure you're using the same connection? Try creating a temporary table and see if that one vanishes too.

Comment: 100% sure, i've tried that and it works fine, the problem is only with attached databases, maybe concurrency have something to do with it?

Comment: Can you share the code?